# Working .off files in opengl

Tags: c, opengl

I have a couple of 3D objects in .off format that I'd like to manipulate using OpenGL + C. Is there a standard, easy way to do this?

Comment: What's an OFF?  [This?](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/off/off.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Based on the link genpfault posted](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/off/off.html), your first issue is that you're working from an ASCII model format. While it's possible to do, you introduce the issue of conversion. Hard, not really, a bit of a pain, yeah. In addition, this format has binary and ASCII variants, so you have to handle two formats.

Now, the details of the format, as noted in this section (taken from the page):

> Line 1 OFF
>
> Line 2 vertex_count face_count edge_count
>
> One line for each vertex: x y z
>   for vertex 0, 1, ..., vertex_count-1 
>   One line for each polygonal face: n v1 v2 ... vn,
>
> the number of vertices, and the vertex indices for each face.

That appears, as first glance, to define things in a very OpenGL friendly format. In fact, I bet you could render straight from the model file. That would only work once, but it means you're off to a good start compared to some of the crazier formats around.

What you'll want to do is take the second line and find the vertex and face count. Store this (pseudo-code snippet to follow). Then go through the vertex and face lists and load each one, saving it in whatever form you like. That process would go something like:

```
List<Vector3> vertices;

Open file model.off
Read line
if ( line == "OFF" )
{
    // We know it's a model
    Read line
    Attributes[] = Split line(' ')
    Vertex count = Attributes[0]
    Face count = Attributes[1]
    // Save edge count if necessary
    For ( vert = 0; vert < vertex count; vert += 1 )
    {
        Read line
        Coordinates[] = Split line(' ')
        float X = FloatFromString(Coordinates[0])
        float Y = FloatFromString(Coordinates[1])
        float Z = FloatFromString(Coordinates[2])
        vertices.push(new Vector3(x, y, z))
    }
    // Repeat for faces
}
```

Now, once you have all the data loaded, you'll need to set it up for rendering. You can have a small function in your model class that simply calls:

```
glBegin(TRIS)
for each ( face )
{
    retrieve the verts from the list
    glVertex3f(x, y, z)
}
```

Obviously it's not exact, but that's the rough idea. You could cache the verts into a VBO on the card or any of a number of other methods, but using simple rendering like this makes the tie between the model format and rendering procedure simpler, in my opinion.

Comment: That link calls it "Object File Format", but I rather like your term (OpenGL Friendly Format) better.

Comment: You're going to have to triangulate those n-gons before you pass them off to `GL_TRIANGLES`.  I suppose you *could* cross all your fingers and toes and hope every polygon you come across is both convex and planar and pass it off to `GL_POLYGON` :)

Comment: @genpfault: You may be able to use tri-fans. I don't see anything on that page about how the verts are set up and no guarantees that they're compatible, so it might take some more work.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: There are a lot of other formats that are designed to be dumped straight into a VBO (NWN1's MDL for OpenGL and NWN2's MDB for DirectX come to mind). Makes them pleasantly simple to load. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find a ".off" file "file structure" documentation if you plan to write an loader.

Something like this (This is for ".MD2"): [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD2_(file_format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD2_%28file_format%29)

Although I suggest that you try to find a converter from ".off" to ".fbx" or ".md2" or any other file format which is widely used.